# How to find a Png file deep inside projects

Tags: objective-c, png, xcode4.5

[image]

There is a file called icon-searchfield.png listed in the list of icon I can find.

It's deep inside a project.

I want to find them. However, I don't know where. I want to get rid reference to that image because a new image is already there.

I browse open all the groups in project navigator and couldn't find it.

I open project.pbxproj file and couldn't find icon-searchfield.png. So how in the earth it shows on the drop down boxes?

I am supposed to use a file with the same name for a picture and existing file with the same name seems to get in the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the project navigator on left side of Xcode and try searching at bottom left corner of Xcode for this image name. If it is present anywhere in the project, it will automatically open that group and will show up there.

Comment: AWESOME. GREAT ANSWER. WOWOWOWOWOWOWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWW.... Didn't know such feature. LIFE SAVER.

Comment: I had to wait 1 minute for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not super-deep into XCode, I would examine from terminal to get clues. E.g. from your project directory -

```
~/Code/ios-samples/NavBar/ $ grep -r "Default.png" .
./NavBar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: 182B3A8511D17401003EE100 /* Default.png */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = image.png; path = Default.png; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
./NavBar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj: 182B3A8511D17401003EE100 /* Default.png */,
...
$
```

Notice the `path = Default.png` there. If your project is referencing to a path outside your project directory, such a `grep` call might give you hints. The `-r` makes `grep` search files recursively.